# GroupBy and collect the whole Row in dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

I have an input dataframe that looks like that

```
+-----+-------------+------+
| Name|      Address|  City|
+-----+-------------+------+
| John|Summer Street|Berlin|
| Mike|  Wood Street|London|
|Peter|   Eagle Road|Berlin|
+-----+-------------+------+
```

My goal is to group by city and collect a list of whole rows that correspond to a particular city. With java streams you could achieve this with the following code:

```
static class SomeObject {
    private final String name;
    private final String address;
    private final String city;

    public SomeObject(String name, String address, String city) {
      this.name = name;
      this.address = address;
      this.city = city;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
      return address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
      return city;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<SomeObject> someObjects = Arrays.asList(
        new SomeObject("John", "Summer Street", "Berlin"),
        new SomeObject("Mike", "Wood Street", "London"),
        new SomeObject("Peter", "Eagle Road", "Berlin")
    );

    Map<String, List<SomeObject>> result = someObjects
        .stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(SomeObject::getCity));
  }
```

And the output would look like that:

```
City: Berlin
SomeObject{name='John', address='Summer Street', city='Berlin'}
SomeObject{name='Peter', address='Eagle Road', city='Berlin'}

City: London
SomeObject{name='Mike', address='Wood Street', city='London'}
```

I am wondering what would be the best way to achieve something similar in spark. I saw there is a `collect_list` function, but you need to specify a **single** column you would want to collect and in my case I would like to collect the **whole Row** (something like the `Function.identity()` in Java). Also, I have presented a simplified example, the dataframe can be more complex and also contain columns of different types (even complex types with nested StructType).

Comment: `groupBy(city).agg(array(name, address, city))`?

Comment: @Igor , are you sure that you want to bring data to driver?

Comment: @mck, this would not work in case of dataframe columns being of different types.

Comment: @Igor how about `.agg(struct(name,...))`?

Comment: @BalajiReddy in the end I will need to bring it to the driver in any case, this is just a small part of the big picture, so for the sake of simplicity we can imagine that both options are fine.

Comment: @mck, thanks, `agg(collect_list(struct(name, ...)))` comes very close to what I need

Answer (score 0):

This could be straightforward if `Dataframe` is converted to `RDD` and `PairRDDFunctions.collectAsMap()` is used as follows.

**Note:**
This method should only be used if the resulting data is expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver's memory.

```
import spark.implicits._

    val fields = Array(StructField("id", LongType, true),
      StructField("name", StringType, true),
      StructField("city", StringType, true))

    val schema = StructType(fields)

    val rows = new java.util.ArrayList[Row]()
    rows.add(0, Row(Some(1l), "Name 1", "City 1"))
    rows.add(1, Row(Some(2l), "Name 2", "City 1"))
    rows.add(2, Row(Some(3l), "Name 3", "City 1"))
    rows.add(3, Row(Some(3l), "Name 4", "City 2"))

   val df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
   df.rdd.groupBy(x => x.getAs[String]("city")).collectAsMap().foreach(println(_))
```

**Output**

```
(City 2,CompactBuffer([3,Name 4,City 2]))
(City 1,CompactBuffer([1,Name 1,City 1], [2,Name 2,City 1], [3,Name 3,City 1]))
```

The reason for `df.rdd` is, `Dataset.groupBy(...)` would return `RelationalGroupedDataset` whereas `RDD.groupBy(...)` would return`RDD<scala.Tuple2<K,scala.collection.Iterable<T>>>` hence `collectAsMap()` can be leveraged.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to stay in the Dataframe realm